# Nhibernate FieldNameLookup throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: nhibernate, ado.net

Every now and then we get this very weird error

```
NHibernate.ADOException: could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.Id as Id37_0_, this_.AREA_ID as AREA2_37_0_, this_.BAT_CHK as BAT3_37_0_, this_.BAT_COD as BAT4_37_0_, this_.BBEACT as BBEACT37_0_, this_.CREDATE as CREDATE37_0_, this_.DEST_LOC as DEST7_37_0_, this_.DOCNR as DOCNR37_0_, this_.DOCTYPE as DOCTYPE37_0_, this_.DUTY_STATUS as DUTY10_37_0_, this_.EAN as EAN37_0_, this_.EXCEPTION_REASON as EXCEPTION12_37_0_, this_.ERROR_TEXT as ERROR13_37_0_, this_.FLOWTYPE as FLOWTYPE37_0_, this_.GOODS_STATUS as GOODS15_37_0_, this_.INSERT_DATETIME as INSERT16_37_0_, this_.MATNR as MATNR37_0_, this_.MVTTYPE as MVTTYPE37_0_, this_.ORDNR as ORDNR37_0_, this_.PACK_ID as PACK20_37_0_, this_.PALNR as PALNR37_0_, this_.PRDACT as PRDACT37_0_, this_.QTYLOAD as QTYLOAD37_0_, this_.SCANNR as SCANNR37_0_, this_.SEQ as SEQ37_0_, this_.SOURCE_LOC as SOURCE26_37_0_, this_.STATUS as STATUS37_0_, this_.TEXT as TEXT37_0_, this_.USER_ID as USER29_37_0_, this_.WH_ID as WH30_37_0_ FROM ZZHTR_RCV this_ WHERE this_.DOCNR = ? and this_.ORDNR = ? and this_.MVTTYPE = ? and this_.WH_ID = ? ]
Positional parameters:  #0>10972365/O #0>1300196311 #0>O #0>NL02
[SQL: <same as above>]
---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Id37_0_
at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
at NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String[] names, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetKeyFromResultSet(Int32 i, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, IDataReader rs, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List[T]()
at Rhino.Commons.RepositoryImplBase1.FindAll(DetachedCriteria criteria, Order[] orders)
at Rhino.Commons.Repository1.FindAll(DetachedCriteria criteria, Order[] orders)
```

The problem is that this error is not showing up every time. I see it's the Id column, but don't understand why it is having issues there.
I'm pretty sure the mapping is OK

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="XX.Business"
                   namespace="XX.Business"
                   default-lazy="true">
  <class name="XX.Business.Receive, XX.Business" table="ZZHTR_RCV" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="AreaCode" column="AREA_ID"/>
    <property name="BatchCheck" column="BAT_CHK"/>
    <property name="BatchCode" column="BAT_COD"/>
    <property name="BbeAct" column="BBEACT"/>
    <property name="CreationDate" column="CREDATE" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="DestinationLocation" column="DEST_LOC"/>
    <property name="DocNr" column="DOCNR"/>
    <property name="DocType" column="DOCTYPE"/>
    <property name="DutyStatus" column="DUTY_STATUS"/>
    <property name="Ean" column="EAN"/>
    <property name="ExceptionReason" column="EXCEPTION_REASON"/>
    <property name="ErrorText" column="ERROR_TEXT"/>
    <property name="FlowType" column="FLOWTYPE"/>
    <property name="GoodsStatus" column="GOODS_STATUS"/>
    <property name="InsertDateTime" column="INSERT_DATETIME" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="MaterialNr" column="MATNR"/>
    <property name="MovementType" column="MVTTYPE"/>
    <property name="OrderNr" column="ORDNR"/>
    <property name="ManufacturingBatch" column="PACK_ID"/>
    <property name="PalletNr" column="PALNR"/>
    <property name="ProdAct" column="PRDACT"/>
    <property name="QuantityLoad" column="QTYLOAD"/>
    <property name="ScanNr" column="SCANNR"/>
    <property name="Sequence" column="SEQ"/>
    <property name="SourceLocation" column="SOURCE_LOC"/>
    <property name="Status" column="STATUS"/>
    <property name="Text" column="TEXT"/>
    <property name="UserId" column="USER_ID"/>
    <property name="WarehouseCode" column="WH_ID"/>


  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class:

```
[XmlRoot("ZZHTR_RCV")]
    public class Receive : DomainObject
    {
        [XmlElement("AREA_ID")]
        public virtual string AreaCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("BAT_CHK")]
        public virtual string BatchCheck { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("BAT_COD")]
        public virtual string BatchCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("BBEACT")]
        public virtual DateTime? BbeAct { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("CREDATE")]
        public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DEST_LOC")]
        public virtual string DestinationLocation { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DOCNR")]
        public virtual string DocNr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DOCTYPE")]
        public virtual string DocType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DUTY_STATUS")]
        public virtual DutyStatus DutyStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EAN")]
        public virtual string Ean { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ERROR_TEXT")]
        public virtual string ErrorText { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("FLOWTYPE")]
        public virtual string FlowType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("GOODS_STATUS")]
        public virtual GoodsStatus GoodsStatus { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("INSERT_DATETIME")]
        public virtual DateTime InsertDateTime { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("MATNR")]
        public virtual string MaterialNr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("MVTTYPE")]
        public virtual string MovementType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ORDNR")]
        public virtual string OrderNr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("PACK_ID")]
        public virtual string ManufacturingBatch { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("PALNR")]
        public virtual string PalletNr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("PRDACT")]
        public virtual DateTime? ProdAct { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("QTYLOAD")]
        public virtual int QuantityLoad { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("SCANNR")]
        public virtual string ScanNr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("SEQ")]
        public virtual int Sequence { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("SOURCE_LOC")]
        public virtual string SourceLocation { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("STATUS")]
        public virtual MobileProcessingStatus Status { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TEXT")]
        public virtual string Text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("USER_ID")]
        public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("WH_ID")]
        public virtual string WarehouseCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EXCEPTION_REASON")]
        public virtual ExceptionReason ExceptionReason { get; set; }
        public virtual string Prodline
        {
            get
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PalletNr) || !this.PalletNr.Length.Equals(18))
                {
                    return "000";
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.PalletNr.Substring(8, 3);
                }
            }
        }
        public virtual string EERPProcessOrder { get; set; }

    }
```

Id is inherited from DomainObject:

```
public abstract class DomainObject:IDomainObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

Table:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AREA_ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [BAT_CHK] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BAT_COD] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BBEACT] [datetime] NULL,
    [CREDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DEST_LOC] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DOCNR] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [DOCTYPE] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [DUTY_STATUS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EAN] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ERROR_TEXT] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EXCEPTION_REASON] [int] NULL,
    [FLOWTYPE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [GOODS_STATUS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [INSERT_DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MATNR] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [MVTTYPE] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [ORDNR] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PACK_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PALNR] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PRDACT] [datetime] NULL,
    [QTYLOAD] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SCANNR] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [SEQ] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SOURCE_LOC] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [STATUS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TEXT] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [USER_ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [WH_ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hey! Did you manage to find what caused this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

We - and others - have also encountered this problem. It seems to be related to *multi-threaded* access to the not-thread-safe `SqlConnection`. The following **really long** post contains more examples and some more detail on the issue: [SQLDataReader.GetOrdinal() fails rarely with IndexOutOfRange](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/74a5db87-c63f-4386-b317-e848dedb2cd9/). There *bbzippo* states:

> It's evident that SqlDataReader reads
>   a result set left over from the
>   previous query executed on the same
>   connection a couple of seconds ago.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any real explanation of why this exception occurs suddenly in code that has been working without a problem for some time.

Some of the suggestions made in the given thread are:

1. Turn connection pooling off, so your connection string would look like e.g. `"Data Source=Sql2005;Initial Catalog=MyDbName;User Id=MyLogin;Password=MyPass;Pooling=false"` (this most likely will mean a performance hit for your application but **is sure to work**)
2. Refactor all `static` code referencing your `SqlConnection` instance(s) to `non-static`
3. Fix possible multi-threaded access to your `SqlConnection`s (this might not be that easy...)

I'm still trying to find the source of the error in our application but it's not that easy because I haven't been able to reproduce it outside our live environment. [Matt Neerincx [MSFT] suggests in one of his answers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/74a5db87-c63f-4386-b317-e848dedb2cd9/#8097bc33-ab26-49d2-b933-620adee94dae) in the above mentioned post to **use different connection strings** and thus different connection pools for different parts of your application to help narrow down the source of the problem.

Another read I found regarding this problem was on the hibernate forums: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2386963, where one poster also had problems with lazy-loading in a multi-threaded scenario.

Hope this will guide anyone in the right direction for a fix.

Comment: thank you so much! unfortunatelly I cannot do more upvotes for this answer and mark it as accepted! :)