# Intermittent IndexOutOfRangeException suggests missing SQL column but resolved by IIS recycle

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception, intermittent

We have an ASP.NET website with lots of traffic that has run happily for years, when suddenly it has began to log `IndexOutOfRangeException` errors when reading some `SqlDataReader` values, as if our SQL stored procedures were missing a column name.

This was a lie, because the URL mentioned in the error log was working fine for me, and was a page I knew a few thousand people would also be hitting every hour; yet the error log only showed it happening 80 times in 5 hours.

Only ten stored procedures appeared to be at fault, so it wasn't errorring on every SQL operation. Just the same ten over and over. Mostly very simple stuff with just `SELECT...WITH(NOLOCK)` in them.

I wasted valuable time making sure the stored procedures were still working (some were unchanged in years) and they were clearly returning the column names correctly. I even tried a `DROP/CREATE` to make sure they were recompiled. **In the end another developer reached for the 'turn it off and on again' solution, and recycled the App Pool in IIS.**

This solved the issue for about ten hours, then it crept back again (again, for about 1% of our visitors), whereupon we restarted IIS, and had another half a day's peace. But how long till it comes back again?!

I will paste what the log says, in case it matters:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 24/04/2018 21:45:45 
Event time (UTC): 24/04/2018 21:45:45 
Event ID: e79bdcb8491b4e38851bd63298afef62 
Event sequence: 35007 
Event occurrence: 1278 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT-1-131690781812076632 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: F:\BLAH\Whatever\ 
    Machine name: MACHINEDB 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 17824 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Whatever 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IndexOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: PhotoCaption
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at Combined.article.DoPhotoStuff(Int32 ArticleID) in F:\stuff\Whatever\photo\view.aspx.vb:line 69
   at Combined.article.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\stuff\Whatever\photo\view.aspx.vb:line 34
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.mywebsite.com/photo/12345 
    Request path: /photo/12345
    User host address: 157.55.39.214 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Whatever
```

The code in each case was something like the following:

```
Dim oRecordSet As SqlDataReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()
oRecordSet.Read()
Blah = oRecordSet("PhotoCaption") 'this line errors
```

There were also smaller numbers of `HttpException` errors, which claimed that `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PhotoLocation'` when executing a `Repeater.DataBind()` - again, the sort of error you expect to get when you refer to a column name that doesn't exist in a recordset. Except those `<asp:Repeater>` details and the stored proc were all working perfectly for the other 99% of viewers.

Comment: Looks like a connection is shared across threads: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74a5db87-c63f-4386-b317-e848dedb2cd9/sqldatareadergetordinal-fails-rarely-with-indexoutofrange?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: related if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734051/intermittent-system-indexoutofrangeexception-when-reading-a-field-from-idataread

Comment: Thanks @rene. The other SO question appears to have the entire website crashing, whereas ours carries on OK. But it could be the same issue so I will look into both those links.

Comment: What is most odd is that this code has worked happily for years, until yesterday!

Comment: If it is related to a connection that is re-used (either from the pool or not) across threads a small change in timing  of code (patch Tuesday maybe?) can reveal threading bugs that never surfaced earlier.

Comment: Wow, you're good! That did happen! And I think we are suffering from the issue where SQL connection pooling is unreliable with the `Shared` keyword. I've got some thinking to do...